# Converting a DataTableReader to SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, ado.net

How to convert datatablereader to sqldatareader? Tried casting without success. 
Reader to table is easy but i need the opposite. I have dataset to be converted to some sqldatareaders.

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to achieve? I know I'm not helping in any way here, but there might be an alternative approach.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9b24d78f-c519-46ad-aa43-df361fe33504/convert-datareader-to-datatable?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: Excute a SqlCommand instead of a Adapter, then you start out with a DataReader instead of a DataSet

Comment: Thats not an option for now :(

Comment: A `DataTableReader` provides for iterating over rows in a `DataTable`, or in other words, iterating over rows of *cached* data. A `SqlDataReader`  provides for iterating rows of data in a Sql *database*. Not really sure what you are trying to do here by converting between a cached data reader and a db backed reader.

Comment: General advise without knowing your context: don't code towards concrete implementations. Have your code rely on `IDataReader` instead of `DataTableReader` and `SqlDataReader`. Then it won't matter if you get the data from a `DataTable` or from an `ExecuteReader` call on a command.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you provide some code how or why you are trying this.

`DataTableReader` and `SqlDataReader` are both works the same way where applicable. No cast is necessary.

In case you need to cast `DataTable` to `SqlDataReader` in C# you can write bellow code:

```
DataTableReader myDataReader = myDataTable.CreateDataReader();
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29976204)